# Bootstrap two responsive menus - collapse one menu when the other menu-button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

There are two search-containers:

```
<div id="navbarSearch" class="navbar-collapse collapse np-mobile-menu"></div>
<div id="navbarMenu" class="navbar-collapse collapse np-mobile-menu"></div>
```

The buttons to collapse this containers:

```
<button class="b1" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSearch" </button>
<button class="b1" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarMenu" </button>
```

Is it possible (and how) as to hide one menu (if is open) when the other menu is clicked - and so open the second menu?

Currently when the navbarMenu is open and i'm gonna open the other menu all two menus are open... You know what I mean?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that toggleClass() triggered by a click() event is what you are after.

- https://api.jquery.com/click/
- http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
 $( ".navbarSearch_button" ).click(function() {
  //alert( "Handler for button_1 called." );
  $( "#navbarSearch" ).toggleClass("navbar-collapse collapse")
 });
 
 $( ".navbarMenu_button" ).click(function() {
  //alert( "Handler for navbarMenu_button called." );
  $( "#navbarMenu" ).toggleClass("navbar-collapse collapse")
 });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="navbarSearch" class="navbar-collapse collapse np-mobile-menu">lala</div>
<div id="navbarMenu" class="navbar-collapse collapse np-mobile-menu">mama</div>

<button class="b1 navbarSearch_button">navbarSearch</button>
<button class="b1 navbarMenu_button" >navbarMenu</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to differentiate the data-target attribute with a unique class or id for your dropdown menus like so:

For your first menu

```
<a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#first">
```

For your second menu:

```
<a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#second">
```

Then you can add that unique id to your nav collapse container:

First

```
<div id="first" class="nav-collapse"> ... </div>
```

Second

```
<div id="second" class="nav-collapse"> ... </div>
```

Comment: That's what I have! But i need to close the other menu (menu 1) when i click on the menu2

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method .collapse() already available in Bootstrap to hide the menu not involved.

Update the html code to this:

```
<div id="navbarSearch" class="navbar-collapse collapse np-mobile-menu"></div>
<div id="navbarMenu" class="navbar-collapse collapse np-mobile-menu"></div>

<button id="navbarSearchButton" class="b1" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSearch"></button>
<button id="navbarMenuButton" class="b1" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarMenu"></button>
```

Then add the js code in separate file:

```
$(function()
{
    $('#navbarSearchButton').on ('click', function() {  $('#navbarMenu').collapse('hide'); });
    $('#navbarMenuButton').on ('click', function() { $('#navbarSearch').collapse('hide'); });
});
```